# Cron Job for everyday except second Sunday and fourth sunday

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, cron, scheduling

What will be the cron job for scheduling a script for every day except second Sunday and fourth Sunday of the month.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to do *exactly* that or just every 14 days starting from the 1st sunday of a specific month and year?

Comment: @garo I just want that my script only runs on everyday of week except second Sunday and fourth sunday of month

Comment: I answered a similar question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/598951 . You will obviously need to make changes but you can use the same method. Tell me if you can't get it too work. But i have to remind you: every 14 is usually a better idea because otherwise the time in between the script will often differ  (months do not always 4 sundays)

Comment: So, is the answer to Garo's question a simple "no"? Can you please answer him directly?

Comment: @garo thanks for the answer, is there any cron job for every day except second Sunday of the month. Again thanks for the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I think it's a bad idea and it would be better to run it every 14 days, this should do what you want. (To run at 4:00 at night)

```
0 4 1-7   * *    test $(date +%u) -eq 7 && ./yourscript.sh
0 4 15-21 * *    test $(date +%u) -eq 7 && ./yourscript.sh
0 4 22-31 * *    test $(date +%u) -eq 7 && ./yourscript.sh
```

**Edit:** I forgot to add minutes -> fixed